# Summary minutes with hours in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel. I make my project in Laravel 5.8.
I have minutes and hours in DB.

I have this code:

```
$workedHours = WorkingTime::where('case_id', $request->id)->sum('hours_worked');
$workedMinutes = WorkingTime::where('case_id', $request->id)->sum('minutes_worked');
```

Example result:

```
$workedHours = 438;
$workedMinutes = 483;
```

I need to add hours over minutes and display the total. For example, 44:12 (44 hours and 12 minutes).

How can i make this?

Comment: how does 438 and 483 make 44:12 ?

Comment: this is example :) $h= 438  hours, $m = 483 minutes. $summary = $h + ($m / 60);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
$workedHours = 438;
$workedMinutes = 483;

$workedHoursInMinutes = $workedHours * 60;
$totalMinutes = $workedHoursInMinutes + $workedMinutes;

$hours = floor($totalMinutes / 60);
$minutes = ($totalMinutes % 60);

dd(sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes));
```

The result will be `446:03`